# My while loop doesn't function correctly after my first input, why?

Tags: python, function, if-statement, while-loop, sum

I'm having trouble with getting the while loop to function correctly in my code.

I want to create a program that randomly generates 2 numbers and asks the user to give the sum of them. This is what I have so far:

```
  import random

def add_random_numbers():
   num1 = random.randint(0, 100)
   num2 = random.randint(0, 100)
   
   print(num1, '+', num2)
   answer = num1 + num2
   
   
   user_answer = int(input("Enter Your Answer: "))
   
   while user_answer != answer:
        if (user_answer > answer):
           print("Sorry, your guess is too high.")
           int(input("\nTry again: "))
           
        if (user_answer < answer): 
             print("Sorry, your guess is too low.")
             int(input("\nTry again: "))
            
add_random_numbers()
```

But once you enter the wrong number and you're prompted to try again, the while loop no longer works. It just keeps repeating the first result. I know it's probably a simple fix but I can't figure it out. What am I missing?

Comment: `int(input("\nTry again: "))` You're asking for more input, but then you discard the answer.  You're not saving it in the `user_answer` variable.

Answer (score 2):

You need to reassign your input back to `user_answer`

```
    while user_answer != answer:
        if (user_answer > answer):
             print("Sorry, your guess is too high.")
             user_answer = int(input("\nTry again: "))
           
        if (user_answer < answer): 
             print("Sorry, your guess is too low.")
             User_answer = int(input("\nTry again: "))
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because you don't reassing `user_answer` on your input "Try again". So that's why it keeps using the first input

Answer (score 1):

So the problem lies in the line where you ask the user to put a new input

```
int(input("\nTry again: "))
```

This line does ask for a new input but the answer isn't assigned anywhere, in order to fix this you only need to rewrite the value of  user_answer as follows

```
user_answer = int(input("\nTry again: "))
```